# Displaying "Disclaimer" screen after the AOSP boot is completed

Tags: android, android-source, boot

I am trying to display a "Disclaimer" screen with some texts or buttons when the Android System is boot-up (After completing the boot animation ). The only way i have found is to add an image of the "Disclaimer" screen inside the bootanimation.zip so that it will display after the boot animation is completed ( image with static texts only ) .

Could you please suggest any ideas for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Is this something that you only need to show *once* on *first boot*?
If so, then you should modify Provision app found in `packages/apps/Provision`, as it's meant for this kind of stuff ( shows after boot animation, and before launcher when device is un-provisioned).

---

If you need to show after each boot then the boot flow UI wise is:

```
boot-animation -> SystemUI -> (Default Launcher)*
```

**Depending on launcher configuration, FallBackHome from  Android Settings might be shown for a couple of seconds before your normal launcher.*

Easiest implementation would be either boot-animation ( like you have it now ), or the main activity of your Launcher application ( usually by default is the Launcher3 module )

Comment: Yes i need to show the same after every boot